# Can I use any variable as image path in gtkmm css

Tags: css, gtkmm

I am new in gtkmm, I have used css in my gtkmm project using css provider class.
In gtkmm css is is it possible to pass image path as variable, and that variable I want to declare in css.

For example:

```
@define-path name "../Images/";
#pickup_button {
    background-image: url("{@name}pickupnml.png");
}
```

If its possible then what is the right syntax. Please help me.